# Private App Distribution for my iOS App - Only for specific clients

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

I am aware that this question has been rattled like an empty can in a trunk for a long time yet I still am not sure how to approach this problem.

### Intention

Allowing my client to download my app by providing a code. So my client can go to a webpage through his iPad, enter in a code, and the downloading of the App starts.

### Solution/Problem

I can do it through AdHoc Distribution, where I can make a webpage that can only show a link to download the App, only after a specific code is authenticated. The **only** problem here is that I need UDID of the device nonetheless. So *here is the problem*, how can I let the user download the app, when he just enters a correct code on some webpage, without having his/her UDID?

I'd really appreciate if you could help me in anyway.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a web based authentication mechanism yourself for allowing a user to download the ipa. Because you wish to be UDID independant, you'll have to enroll to the enterprise program - a simple iOS developer program will not suit your needs (limited to 100 specific devices).

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [iOS Enterprise Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) is for.

*Get tools and resources for developing proprietary, in-house iOS apps that you can distribute to your employees.*

**No** UDID needed. **No** 100 device limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now using redemption links with [private app distribution](https://getonthestore.com/private-app-distribution/). You still need to go through App Review, but users will be able to download your app without you needing to know their device UDID and without the app publicly being available on the App Store.